# Possible to prevent access to a variable declared in the scope or as a function argument?

Tags: scope, namespaces, rust

Say we have a variable which (after being used for its intended purpose) should *never* be accessed.

*(doing so may be valid as far as Rust is concerned, but its contents is logically not valid anymore within the context of the application).*

In Python for example, you can simply do:

```
del myvar;
```

Is there a way to disallow future access for variables declared in the body of a function or references passed as arguments?

---

Note that typically scope can be used for this, however that doesn't work for function arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass it to any function that consumes its argument (as long as you have its ownership in the scope you want to do it in). An example is [drop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html), which does exactly (and [only](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/up/src/libcore/mem.rs.html#519)) that. Any attempts to use it afterwards would result in "use after move" errors.

Simple example with `foo` as the block where you want to delete the argument `s`:

```
fn foo(s: String) -> whatever {
    println!("{}", s);

    drop(s); // fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }

    println!("{}", s); // error: use of moved value: `s` [E0382]

    // do stuff
}
```

Note that this is only possible for types which do not implement `Copy`.

**Edit**: I think I found a solution for `Copy`able types; they can be `Box`ed, after which they can be `drop`ped:

```
let x = Box::new(5);
println!("{}", x); // ok

drop(x);

println!("{}", x); // error: use of moved value
```

Comment: As noted in the question, this doesn't work for function arguments.

Comment: @ideasman42: Sure it does.  `fn f(s: String) { drop(s); /* s is no longer valid */ }`.

Comment: That comment was before the edit in the question and before the edit in my answer :) - I suggested adding a wrapper scope first, before that option was excluded.

Comment: This doesn't work for arguments which are references.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but this was not a condition. I don't think it is possible with a reference, since the whole point of borrowing an object is that it can still be used afterwards.

Comment: This was noted in the title: "Possible to prevent access to a variable declared in the scope or as a **function argument?**", edited question to make it more explicit.

Comment: You would have to write "a function argument, even if it is a **reference**".

Comment: @ljedrz: I would side with ideasman42 here. In programming, you should **never assume** something just because it makes your life easier. If it is not specified whether this should work for `Copy` types or not, then you cannot assume that `Copy` types are excluded from the question just because it's easier for you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that's true, but I think ideasman42 was talking here about passing references, not values. I only covered non-`Copy`able types, because those were the ones I knew how to manage.

Answer (score 5):

There is an ugly workaround that works even for `Copy` values: Shadowing.

```
enum Void {}

fn foo(x: i32) -> whatever {
    println!("{}", x);

    let x: Void;
    // Now `x` refers to an uninitialized variable with which you
    // couldn't do anything even if it was initialized
}
```

However, the error messages are horrendous, and the intent is far from clear. I strongly urge you to reconsider whether you need this ability this badly. For the record, I have never seen explicit `del` being used for this purpose in Python code. Nor do I recall such a thing in any of the other code I've read.

Comment: Its useful in Python for functions that 1) are naturally serial and don't warrant being split into many functions. 2) define temp variables you want to explicitly end possible access (or accidental access). Checking over CPython's code shows this is used in core modules such as `os`, `functools`, `datetime`, `pdb` & `xml.etree`

Comment: It will work, but you are right about ugly - I'd even call it an anti-pattern. Also, it stops working after the scope of the function is over.